# Location triangulation by signal strength

Tags: open-source, library, geo-location, algorithms

I am looking for a library to help locate devices by triangulation (preferably C/C++, but I could consider other languages).

I would prefer open-source, so that I can compile it for different platforms. As a worst case, I would accept a Linux executable, maybe even Windows.

The basic idea, as you know if you can answer this question, is that there are a bunch of routers/cell towers/etc – let’s call them servers, and a bunch of devices moving around.

Each server is aware of the devices. I will go for BLE, but the principle is the same for instance for tracking cell-phones: by measuring the signal strength between each device and each “server”, we can triangulate and (roughly) determine the location of the device.

Of course, the system needs to be configurable, to add/remove devices & Servers. It is probably also necessary to introduce details of signal obstructions, such as walls & pillars, etc.